# How to limit an android app not to be displayed in main menu of the device?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I am installing an app(say app1) progamatically from other app(say app2). All I am trying is that app1 is not displayed in main menu of the device and could be started only by the app2.
If this is possible how could I implement this.Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app1 manifest should not contain any component with

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

then it will not be displayed in the Launcher

Comment: Just Complete the answer:
Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);

for launching app1 from app2

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

in the manifest of app1 with

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```

Then it will be launched from app2 and wont be displayed in the application list(main menu)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy. In your manifest, there is usually an Activity. This Activity has an intent-filter. The entry point of your application contains an intent-filter that looks like:

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If you don't put those 2 values in the intent-filter, your activity does not appear on the main menu.

Yet, you can still call it directly via any other kind of intent-filter.

Comment: how can i call it using different intent-filter

Comment: read intent-filter documentation. it has a lot of good stuff in it